# How can i implement a Web Server in Android Studio (Java) and react to requests?

Tags: java, android, webserver

Is it possible to create a local web server in Java (Android Studio IDE) and send broadcasts containing e.g the parameter f (http://localhost:8888/?f=SOMEDATA) to another app??
Thanks

Comment: Yes you can make an app that is a webserver on an Android device. For the rest i dont understand who is broadcasting what. And to which app. It are browsers that communicate with webservers.

Comment: First, i only want to do a simple web server which is just local on e.g port 8899 and listens to requests. If a request is received, it runs some code i'll define later to transmit the request data to the app Automate (https://llamalab.com/automate/) for further processing (e.g My App posts a notification with the data which is processed and then canceled by Automate immediately)

Comment: Have a look at NanoHttpD to build your app a webserver.